# how to handle 'unable to resolve request' in yii 1.x?

Tags: yii

my url is like

```
e.g http://me.mydomain.com/admin/view/1
```

that url is reached by clicking a list item from

```
e.g 
http://me.mydomain.com/admin/list
```

hence the number 1 in the first url stands for an ID.

but when I manually put something like this in the url

```
e.g
http://me.mydomain.com/admin/view/asdfasdf1234
```

and pressed the enter key of the keyboard, I am getting an error that says

```
Unable to resolve the request "http://me.mydomain.com/admin/view/asdfasdf1234".
```

how to handle this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I took files from GIT repository in to my windows , localhost dev environment and it gave me error URL not found Error404 , something like that.

Step1- Change config/main.php as follows

```
'urlManager' => array( 
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => array(              
                        '/' => '/view',
                        '//' => '/',
                        '/' => '/',

            ),

        )
```

Step-2 Now modify ur application .htaccess file , which shoul be outside just protected folder some rewite-rules as follows....
RewriteEngine on

```
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Step 3- Restart your apache.and check in browser

Step4- Change http.config with Allow Override All , inplace of None.(For security point of view recheck this step).

**This may or may not help you**

Answer (score 0):

Check the **case sensitivity**. That may cause problem.

Comment: it's not with the case sensitivity.. because as I said, when i manually input a non id in the url as parameter.  manually "pressed the enter key of the keyboard".. that's the time am getting the error that I mentioned. but if the id is actually existing in the db. it don't have error at all